# Can multi-instrumental sound be reconstructed from a waveform?

Tags: waves, acoustics, signal-processing

This question came about when I saw someone wearing clothing with a waveform on it. I wondered if it would be possible to reconstruct the original sound from the printed waveform.

I understand that a waveform is frequency over time. I have previously researched waveforms however most of the tutorials are about single tones, rather than multi-instruments.

**My understanding - which may not be correct - is that wave forms of music are simply the frequency of all the instruments added together.** Eg, the wave form of a drum, with the wave form of a guitar added on top, results in a new waveform that sounds like both instruments playing at the same time.

So while it may not be possible to capture the 'drum part' and the 'guitar part' separately from the image on the clothing (without further analysis), it's possible to recreate the music (the drum and guitar playing at the same time) from the image on the clothing.

I have very little expertise in signal processing and appreciate any help and corrections here.

Comment: Vinyl LP records perform this task. The waveform is scratched into the plastic and read back with a needle.

Answer (score 3):

> clothing with a waveform on it.

I have two T-shirts like this!

> I understand that a waveform is frequency over time.

No. It's the sound pressure over time.

> My understanding - which may not be correct - is that wave forms of music are simply the frequency of all the instruments added together. Eg, the wave form of a drum, with the wave form of a guitar added on top, results in a new waveform that sounds like both instruments playing at the same time.

Sort of. You add the time domain wave forms of the different instruments together (typically with some processing and panning).

> it's possible to recreate the music (the drum and guitar playing at the same time) from the image on the clothing.

No. The sound pressure wave form has WAY more detail than you can print on a piece of clothing. A wave form that's a few seconds long will require 100s of thousands of individual samples.

**EDIT**

If the cloth had sufficient resolution (in both spatial dimensions) you could certainly reconstruct the wave form again. That would simply be a digital representation of the wave, same as any representation in a computer or media device. So, in a sense, it's a really odd way to store a wave file :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I feel like the detail of the cloth has obscured the discussion. Say the cloth was infinitely large and printed with 44,100 vertical bars for every second. Would the original multi instrumental music be recognisable?

Comment: @mikemaccana, the answer is yes. You would need to scan the printed waveform into a sound-creating software package first, but then you're good to go!

Comment: @nielsnielsen thanks! If you add that into the question I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @mikemaccana, sorry MIke-it's HILMAR's answer!

Comment: Ah sorry, my question was addressed to @hilmar